# How should data be displayed and updated in a Webapp from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am writing a web app for the first time using Firebase and I'm having trouble understanding best practice for retrieving data from Firebase and updating pre-existing HTML tags.

For instance:

```
projectRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

    $('#project_ul').append('<li data-project="'+snap.Name+'"><img src="'+img+'" />' + 
       '<span class="li_name">'+snap.Name+'</span><span class="li_desc">'
        +snap.Description+'</span><span class="li_date">Expected End Date: '
        +snap.DueDate+'</span></li>');

});
```

Works to get next level children from my `Users` level in my Firebase. When I add new Nodes, it appends the new ones to the list, as expected. When I try to use:

```
projectRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {


});
```

I have thus far failed in developing code that updates the existing li's, instead it always appends new ones. For instance, if the `Name` of the project is updated in Firebase, how would I go to the correct `li` and change its `.html()`? What is best practice to take in Firebase JSON objects to construct html elements that can be easily updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case what I normally do is put an `id` on the generated HTML that allows me to match it up with the child node in Firebase. E.g.

```
$('#project_ul').append('<li id="'+snap.key()+'" ...
```

Then when you get a `child_changed` (or `child_removed` or `child_moved`) event, you can look up the existing element and update/remove/move it:

```
project.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
  var li = $('#'+snapshot.key());
  li.html(...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to do something like this, but I couldn't quite figure out how. It's so simple, and everything I tried was so convoluted. Lol. Thanks!